# Change the color of MUI Autocomplete option

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using the `Autocomplete` of Material UI and I have a list with the attribute Color. I have to render option by option with the respective color in option background.

***Here's a example:***

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";

export default function ComboBox() {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={params => {
        return (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            label="Combo box"
            variant="outlined"
            fullWidth
          />
        );
      }}
    />
  );
}

const top100Films = [
  { title: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994, color: '#FF0000' },
  { title: "The Godfather", year: 1972, color: '#FF5555' },
  { title: "Avatar", year: 2010, color: '#FFFFFF' },
  // Plus a bunch more
];
```

Comment: can you elaborate on what you have tried and what is not working

Comment: I tried to use the prop ListboxProps with background style, but it change all the list

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `renderOption` to render the style conditionally for each option in the latest version of MUI.

```
<Autocomplete
  renderOption={(props, option) => {
    const { title, color } = option;
    return (
      <span {...props} style={{ backgroundColor: color }}>
        {title}
      </span>
    );
  }}
  {...}
/>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 64171767/change-the-color-of-material-ui-autocomplete-option]

Comment: Is it possible to style each option on MUI v4? I've been following your solution only to notice it doesn't work. There's a big difference now in the parameters for render option.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the CSS like this:

```
.MuiAutocomplete-inputRoot[class*="MuiOutlinedInput-root"] {
    background: #ffff
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This will change the options color.

In the code, the `sx` prop I have included the css properties for the whole option menu, selected option and while hovered in the selected option for the Autocomplete component:

```
<Autocomplete
 limitTags={1}
 disablePortal
 id="simple-search"
 value={select.region}
 onChange={handleChange("region")}
 options={region}
 sx={{
   width: { sm: "100%", md: 340 },
   "& + .MuiAutocomplete-popper .MuiAutocomplete-option": {
        backgroundColor: "#363636",
    },
   "& + .MuiAutocomplete-popper .MuiAutocomplete-option[aria-selected='true']":
      {
        backgroundColor: "#4396e6",
      },
   "& + .MuiAutocomplete-popper .MuiAutocomplete-option[aria-selected ='true'] 
   .Mui-focused":
   {
      backgroundColor: "#3878b4",
   },
  }}
            disableCloseOnSelect
            multiple
            renderInput={(params) => (
              <TextField {...params} label="Region" color="info" />
            )}
          />
```