# MUI v4 - How to style specific option in AutoComplete

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

I'm trying to custom style a specific option in my autocomplete. And I'm following this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64171767/change-the-color-of-mui-autocomplete-option?rq=1) however I cannot get it to work with the exact `option` element. I can only style the `span`

Here is the code in that solution:

```
<Autocomplete
  renderOption={(props, option) => {
    const { title, color } = option;
    return (
      <span {...props} style={{ backgroundColor: color }}>
        {title}
      </span>
    );
  }}
  {...}
/>
```

The solution above doesn't work for me. Maybe it's the version difference since I'm using mui v4. Even in the parameters for the `renderOption` in that example vs my code is different in structure.

Below is my own code. I'm trying to purposely hide some options. And what I can get from this is just only the `span` and not the parent `option` gets the styling or gets hidden which is an obvious outcome but I still leave it here because I'm trying to make a workaround referencing the example above. I need the option element to be hidden so it doesn't appear in the autocomplete list(but the value is still there in the background and selectable via input)

```
<Autocomplete
  renderOption={(option) => {
   
    return (
      <span style={{ display: option.display, visibility: option.visibility }}>
        {title}
      </span>
    );
  }}
  {...}
```

My Options Data:

```
const top100Films = [
  { title: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994, display: "none", visibility: "hidden" },
  { title: "The Godfather", year: 1972, display: "none", visibility: "hidden"},
  { title: "Avatar", year: 2010, display: "block", visibility: "visible" }
  
];
```

Any thoughts how to custom style each option for MUI v4? Please let me know if there's a way without upgrading to MUI latest version.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the MUI v4 structure. I assume there's always a wrapping <li> element? So in this case you end up being able to hide your span, but the parent <li> element is still there? If what I said is accurate, and you're needing to remove the <li> element, I think you're out of luck with v4. If you're OK with <li> elements being there and you just want "empty" ones to not be visible, you could get some css applied that could achieve that.

Comment: yes the parent element is still there. I can get the span content to be hidden, but there is still the li container, so it's showing an empty element but the parent is still there and obviously part of the list since I can hover on it.

Comment: Could you post more about the li css? I think you could apply styles such that empty li's have no height/width and therefore wont have any of the hover effects, etc. At least not visibly to the user. This is one unfortunate side effect of using components in the lab project. They have some oversights such as what you're experiencing.